# raycasting, Как максимально оптимально проводить эти 2 миллиона пространственных проверок?

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр, 3d, raytracing

Пару дней назад мне стало очень интересно как в играх происходит отрисовка кадров, прочитав пару умный статей и посмотрев все невероятно умные видеоматериалы на эту тему я попытался реализовать свою простенькую программку для отрисовки небольшой сцены.

Сделал я на js так как это просто проще и делается для того что бы поиграться и понять как это всё робит.
Поле того как я сравнил своё поделие с разными ознакомительными демками каких-то гениев кодинга а просто невероятно удивился насколько время отрисовки моей даже более простой сцены отличается от времени отрисовки кадра программ гениев кодинга и задался вопросом. Как ёптыть так?

Моя программа рендерить сцену более чем за пол минуты, когда программы гениев кодинга делают это с более сложными сценами и отрисовкой теней более чем в 10 раз быстрее (в обоих случаях отрисовка происходит на cpu).

В каком моменте я допустил ошибку при проектировании сваей программы? помогите пожалуйста, я очень хочу понять 3д и научится делать свои 3д проекты.

вот моя программа - https://github.com/aguree/my-1st-raycasting-program

Comment: А что, гении кодинга тоже на CPU и 2D-context работают? А почему не WebGL?

Comment: да, и у них каким-то неведомым образом робит получше

Comment: в этом и весь парадокс сопсна

Comment: Может они ArrayBuffer используют, в смысле типизированные массивы? В общем то что тут можно ответить если вы ссылаетесь на работу третьих лиц, с которой нам надо сравнить? Приведите и их код тогда.

Comment: например вот эта демка

Comment: https://www.gabrielgambetta.com/computer-graphics-from-scratch/demos/raster-11.html

Comment: или эта гениальная штука https://github.com/chetca/raycasting_js